# Compute module CM3+ change GPIO 37 alt function

Tags: gpio, pigpio, compute-module-3

I am trying to switch the alt functions on GPIO36 and GPIO37 on CM3+. I installed and ran the pigpiod service. I find that for GPIOs greaters than 27 that pigs command returns "no permission to update". Since CM3+ has 46 GPIO pins versus 28 for raspberry pi 3, how do i work around this limitation to switch the alt functions for GPIO28 to GPIO45 (specifically GPIO36 and GPIO37 in my case)

Regards

---

Comment: That command obviously doesn't support the compute module. Have you tried `raspi-gpio`?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth while to raise an issue at https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/issues

pigpio should automatically recognise the GPIO available on each Pi model.  It seems to be failing to recognise your model.

In the mean time I suggest you start the pigpio daemon with the `-x -1` option.

See [pigpio daemon options](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html).

E.g. from the command line

`sudo pigpiod -x -1`

I don't know how to integrate that option into the service you are using.